# how to split a string going backwards in java

Tags: java, split

I have a binary string which i would like to split. The string is of variable length and needs to be split into 3 sections; The tag, index, and block offset. I have the length of the index and the block offset, but not the tag, and I am trying to separate the tag from the rest of the string. is there a way to do that when the length of the index and block offset are known? (I want to split them backwards because the tag is of variable length but the index and block offset are constant)

---

Example(written in hex for simplicity):

```
String[1]: 400341a0
String[2]: df7c48
index length: 2 hex
block offset length: 3 hex    
Output[0]: {400, 34, 1a0}
Output[1]: {d, f7, c48}
```

Comment: Simple `substring` will get you what you wantl.

Comment: When you write it in hex "for simplicity" - are your lengths in terms of characters, or in terms of bits?  If it's the former then it's simple, but if it's the latter then `String` is probably the wrong datatype for your arguments (since they're a wrapper around an array of *characters* - nothing to do with bits).

Comment: He says he has a binary string.

Comment: Also worth considering [apache commons substring](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substring(java.lang.String,%20int)) supports passing negative indexes to count from the back.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle well the instructions come in as hex but I have the length of the index and block offset in binary, so I thought a bit of translation and casting would do the job if I had the method of splitting.

Comment: @sbk Sorry, I am a bit new to java but how do you use the apache commons substring? I tried using it and eclipse is not liking it at all. used `s = s.substringAfter(s, " ");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about +-1 but I think it's good.

```
int length = s.length;
int blockOffsetIndex = length - BLOCK_OFFSET_LENGTH;
blockOffset = s.substring(blockOffsetIndex  - 1, length );

int indexIndex = blockOffsetIndex - INDEX_LENGTH;
indexStr = s.substring(indexIndex - 1, indexIndex + INDEX_LENGHT);

rest = s.substring(0, indexIndex -1);
```

As @sdk suggested, [Apache StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substring%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) is also a very good solution.